# Clear text field in a form and resubmit it

Tags: html, forms

I have a form in html (generated in php), which contains also a text field. 
To submit the form I use a submit button and the results appear on the left side of the page. Now, I would like to add another button which would clean the text in the text field
and resubmit the form (with `value=""` in the text field). Do you have any idea how to do it?
Simple `<input type="reset">` does not submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your button should be like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="DeleteText();" value="Delete text" />
```

and your javascript code:

```
function DeleteText() {
   document.getElementById('my_text_input_id').value = '';
   document.getElementById('my_form_id').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose the text box has `id="myText"` and the new button has `id="clearBtn"`, and the form has `id=myForm`.  You can do the following:

```
$(#clearBtn).on("click",function() {
    $('#myText').val("");
    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
})
```

This is untested, but proposes an idea.  Also, This is a jquery solution, which I recommend over pure javascript in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 brings us the "placeholder" attribute, which allows for a Pure CSS implementation of this.

```
<input type="text" name="focus" required class="search-box" placeholder="Enter search term" />
```

I have successfully used Shidhin's solution, found here:

http://codepen.io/shidhincr/pen/ICLBD